# slider wont load unless you scrolldown on mobile, slick.js carousel

Tags: jquery

I use slick.js for my carousel. Everything is working fine on desktop but in my mobile I have this weird problem where the slider doesn't load correctly until I scrolldown. Have anyone here also experienced this, behavior.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.row-one-container .sliders-container').slick({
    infinite: true,
    dots: true,
    arrows: true,
    responsive: [
        {
            breakpoint: 500,
            settings:{
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                infinite: true,
            }
        }
    ]
  });
 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior of the page is caused by the WP Rocker plugin you are using.

With the active "**Delay JavaScript Execution**" option ("*File Optimization*" tab), all scripts on your website are loaded only after the user performs some action (e.g. will move the cursor). This applies to both the mobile and desktop versions.

Excluding just `jquery` and `slick.js` from lazy load in WP Rocket settings should solve the problem.

Comment: In the documentation, at the end of [this page](https://docs.wp-rocket.me/article/1655-troubleshoot-delay-javascript-execution-issues), there are "Basic Examples" and "Exclusions" sections.

Comment: thank you so much